# Align glyphicon with label

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have following markup:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <label class="labelTextFormat">Tags</label>
        <button><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" style=""></span></button>
        <button><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" style=""></span></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which gives me following output:

[image: Glyphicon]

I want to display them next to Label. How should I do that?

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AXxxQy)

Comment: Style your elements to be `display: inline-block;`

Comment: Its working fine.Do elaborate the things correctly...

Comment: @Paulie: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AXxxQy

Comment: @Vigensh: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AXxxQy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `label` is 100% wide

Remove that

```
.labelTextFormat {
    font-weight: normal; 
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #a1ebff; 
    padding-top: 6px;
    float: left;
}
```

```css
    .labelTextFormat {
        font-weight: normal; 
        font-size: 18px;
        color: #a1ebff; 
        padding-top: 6px;
        float: left;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <label class="labelTextFormat">Tags</label>
    <button><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" style=""></span></button>
    <button><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" style=""></span></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalNorm" type="button">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Tags</button>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!